# ng-grid server side paging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm a little confused on how to use the sever side paging for ng-grid.  (http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/)

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this on the server side?  The example shows a static json file.  How and where are the parameteres set for limit and offset so I can adjust my sql query and output.  It seems on the surface it is all loaded at once.

Thanks.  I know this may get down votes but had to take the chance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you because I use the SLIM Framework for routing and MEEKRO as mysql famework on my serverside. But it comes down to this:

This is what my `getPagedDataAsync` function looks like

```
    $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, sorting,searching) {
            $http.get('db_api.php/'+pageSize+'/'+page+'/'+sorting.sortfield+'/'+sorting.sortdir+'/'+searching).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.profiles = data.result;
                    $scope.totalServerItems = data.all;
                    $scope.filtered = data.filtered;
                    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                            $scope.$apply();
                    }
            });
    };
```

It sends a GET request to my php script with the parameters that are gathered by the watchers. Unlike the example this takes also the `sortOptions` into account. If you don't want to use a routing framework on the server side you should replace the slashes with the usual questionmark ampersand notation.

By looking at your rep I think this should already give you a clue. Come back if you need further help on the sql query.